# Lenovo Twist Touchpad Problems

Tags: touchpad, lenovo

I have a Lenovo Twist (laptop that converts to a tablet) Win 8 with a touchscreen. I've tried to load several versions of Linux and the problem I run into is the touchpad is not recognized. The touchscreen works but the touchpad isn't loaded when I go into control panel. I posted on a different forum and was told I should do a insmod psmouse but that did't work.

Any idea how I can load drivers for my touchpad?

Answer (score 1):

This appears to be a BIOS issue.  Other users have reported that versions prior to 1.53 seem unaffected by this issue, however if you simply use the touchscreen to initiate a restart, the touchpad will be recognized the second time.  No one seems to have yet reported a good explanation for this.

Be careful flashing to earlier BIOS versions as it seems some critical fixes are also in place post-1.53.  In my case, the 1.53 had a serious problem with my internal network adapter, and the Twist would not boot without first manually disconnecting it.

Comment: For reference: https://bugs.launchpad.net/ubuntu/+source/linux/+bug/1210748/